# If $A= (QU_2)\begin{bmatrix}\Omega_k & O\\ O& \Lambda\end{bmatrix} (PV_2)^T$, When will diagonal elements of $\Omega_K, \Lambda$ be singular values?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, singular-values

Suppose we show 
$$A= (QU_2)\begin{bmatrix}\Omega_k & O\\ O& \Lambda\end{bmatrix} (PV_2)^T$$

where $\Omega_k$ and $\Lambda$ are the diagonal matrices from the SVD of two other matrices.

- When will it be the case that the diagonal elements of $$\begin{bmatrix}\Omega_k & O\\ O& \Lambda\end{bmatrix}$$ are singular values of $A$, and that $$(QU_2)\begin{bmatrix}\Omega_k & O\\ O& \Lambda\end{bmatrix} (PV_2)^T$$ is a SVD of $A$?

Comment: If it fulfills that $QU_2$, $PV_2$ unitary and equality holds.

Comment: @mathreadler sorry just edited question significantly. But that does help thank you

Comment: The definition of SVD says that if you have three matrices, two unitary, $W,Z$ : $WW^T=I, ZZ^T=I$ and one diagonal $\Gamma$, then they will be the singular value decomposition of matrices $W\Gamma Z^T$ , $Z\Gamma W^T$. So if you have any matrix equal to that product of matrices with those properties then those matrices are that matrix's SVD.

Comment: @mathreadler Thank you. That is what I was looking for (if you post as answer I will accept). I was confused because All I have seen in the book I am reading so far is that any $m\times n$ matrix has a SVD.

Comment: This is awkward in the sense if $m\neq n$ how do you write the diagonal in the middle, you need to know that the number of non zero singular values is equal to rank which is $\le \min (m,n)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of SVD says that if you have three matrices, two unitary, $$W,Z : \cases{WW^T=I\\ ZZ^T=I}$$ and one diagonal $\Gamma$, then they will be the singular value decomposition of matrices $W\Gamma Z^T$ and $Z\Gamma W^T$.

So if you have any matrix $A$ equal to that product of matrices with those properties then those matrices are that matrix's SVD.

$$A=W\Gamma Z^T$$